# File History in GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am looking for a solution in GitKraken to view complete file history past renamed changes. I have been using the fuzzy finder in GitKraken Free Version since very long but couldn't find any option to view the history of the file before it is renamed.

In Git, this could be achieved by: `git log --follow filename`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If git correctly realized the file was renamed, GitKraken will show you if you look at the files history (via Fuzzy Finder or right click -> File History). Below the latest commit shown in the commit list, it will say `RENAMED from <old_filename>`. When you click `<old_filename>`, the old files history will be shown, with a hint at the topmost commit saying `RENAMED to <new_filename>`.

[image: New named file history]

Bottom of new files history

[image: Old named file history]

Top of old files history